# Rails strong params not seeing params in ajax post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

This button is nested in form that saves hospitals names independently of the main form. I've tried several different attempts at adjusting params including removing ".require(:hospital)". I have tried to add "controller" and "action" to hospital_params. I've tried every other solution  I could find. Thanks for the help!

**Error:**

```
Started POST "/hospitals" for ::1 at 2020-07-12 12:42:09 -0500
Processing by HospitalsController#create as */*
{"controller"=>"hospitals", "action"=>"create"}
  User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 102], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/hospitals_controller.rb:14:in `create'
Completed 400 Bad Request in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms | Allocations: 1706)


  
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: hospital):
  
app/controllers/hospitals_controller.rb:48:in `hospital_params'
app/controllers/hospitals_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

**Params:**

```
  def hospital_params
    params.require(:hospital).permit(:name)
  end
```

**Ajax:**

```
$("#save-hospital-button").click(function () {
    var hospitalName = $("input[id='transport[hospital_name_input]'").value;
    var mydata = {
      hospital: {
        name: hospitalName
      },
    };
    Rails.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: `/hospitals`,
      data: mydata,
      success: function (response) {},
      error: function (response) {},
    });
    return false;
  })
```

**Controller:**

```
  def create
    puts params
    @hospital = current_user.hospitals.new(hospital_params)
    
    respond_to do |f|
      if @hospital.save
        f.html { redirect_to action: 'index', notice: "Your settings were updated!" }
        f.js
      else
        f.html { render :new, notice: "Your settings were NOT updated!" }
      end
    end
  end
```

**html.erb:**

```
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="add_hospital_form">
    <%= f.hidden_field current_user.id, id: "current_user" %>
    <%= f.text_field "transport[hospital_name_input]", label: "Other facility name:" %>
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-success mb-5
    " id="save-hospital-button" type="button">Save Facility to List</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: You will have to prevent the button from doing the default by taking a parameter in the click function and do `event.stopPropagation();`. This will stop the button from submitting

Comment: Thanks, it currently doesn't submit the form but it does process the post request thus resulting in the error message.

Comment: Can you post your full form code

Comment: It's over 400 loc , do you think that is messing the params up?

Comment: Did you try what i mentioned above? I suspect the code isn't being called because the form submits before the function can be called

Comment: yes, same error

Comment: In your controller you have a debug line of `puts params`. Can you tell us what that prints? Also add `puts hospital_params` and make sure it's actually what you are expecting it to be.

Comment: Personally I would make the `save-hospital-button` a `link_to...` and just style it was a button with an ajax call. That way it is not possibly acting as a submit button. I have a page of links that all are styled as buttons and they use `remote: true` and I am able to toggle their values via ajax and change their color to reflect that on save.

Comment: Hi, I left in the error message line 3, {"controller"=>"hospitals", "action"=>"create"}, I have added both of those to hospital_params and no change. I think i'm zeroing in though, it looks like my var hospitalName is empty even though when i run it in console it pulls the correct value.

Comment: I think your problem is here; `var hospitalName = $("input[id='transport[hospital_name_input]'").value;` 
Can you show the actual rendered HTML for that field? I don't see you explicitly setting an ID on that in the ERB code.

Comment: I verified it was there, im using a bootstrap forms helper that adds it im guessing, I changed it to this:var hospitalName = document.getElementById("transport[hospital_name_input]").value; Now it is committing to db but still get a 500 error in my create block and argument error but it does save to db atleast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Using Rails.ajax the data has to be in this format: 'hospital[name]=test'.
When using jquery ($.ajax) the format above will work. Hope this saves some else from wasting as much time as I did.